# firebase authentication 3rd provider choose firebase or another solution

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I do like the firebase db solution beause it is fast and you can subcscribe to changes but my one question is about user access. I do want to build a system with one masterpassword where you dont ID identify every user all the way into Googles firebase. I want to store user ID on another server and not inside firebase. is this doable with firebase at all? How do you go about building a 3:rd party Authentication provider in firebase? I do not want to store identification data inside firestore but in another place. Is this a dealbreaker in a way I should use any other db solution?

Answer (score 0):

When you [implement a custom authentication provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) you control pretty much everything out the user token, including its UID and the claims in there.

There is no requirement to store the identification in Firestore, or to even use Firestore either, but if you sign in the user with the custom token as documented in the link above, their token will be available in the `request.auth` variable in your Firestore security rules automatically.

If you want to get a feeling at how easy/hard it is to implement a custom authentication provider, have a look at this simple example of a [username+password provider built on top of Cloud Functions](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/username-password-auth) (which is not required either, but just used in this example).